# Can I make a model save() method dependent on a successful payment?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to give users the ability to create a model, but I want the saving of the model to be dependent on a successful payment. I know I could just save the model instance and use web hooks to modify a bool field from false to true upon successful payment, to show that it has been paid for, but is there a way to hold the initial data in space, and only commit it to the database if a successful payment signal is received? I've looked into pre_save signals, but not sure if I'm on the right track.

For example, if the following is my form save logic, what could I do instead of instance.save()? Because, ideally, I would rather not save the instance and take up space in the database if the customer isn't going to pay for it.

```
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    data = {k: v for form in form_list for k, v in form.cleaned_data.items()}
    instance = Example.objects.create(**data)
    instance.payment_status = 'Pending'
    instance.save()
    context = instance
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('process-payment', kwargs={'pk': instance.pk, 'name': instance.name}))
```

Comment: You definitely can have a workflow where you verify a payment before saving some data, but this question as it currently stands is far too broad to give a reasonable answer to. It also depends on what payment method/processor you're using. I'd suggest you first have a look at the numerous payment processing apps written for Django (for a variety of processors) to see how they implement this workflow (maybe even use one of them, which is probably better than rolling your own).

Comment: @solarissmoke - Solar I have a payment processor integrated already, and I can include metadata in with the payment. Would you recommend I include the metadata in with the form, do not save the instance, when successful payment is processed return metadata to view with web hook, and only then create and save model? I added some to the question to hopefully make things more clear.

Comment: You could write some logic for the returned values from the processor. If the payment fails, then ```pass```.